# Getting a fixed number of records using Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to create a Spring Boot application, where I need to fetch the records from the database and make a call to the REST API for each record fetched from the database. But instead of fetching all the records at once I want to retrieve in batch sizes, say 10, make the rest call for them and then fetch another 10 and do the same, until last record. I am using spring-data-jpa. How can I achieve that?

P.S.: Its a multi-threaded call and DB is the Amazon DynamoDB

**My code till now:**

Controller:

```
//Multi Threaded Call to rest
@GetMapping("/myApp-multithread")
public String getQuoteOnSepThread() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    System.out.println("#################################################Multi Threaded Post Call######################");
    ExecutorService executor= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    List<Future<String>> myFutureList= new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
    long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;


    ***//Here instead of fetching and calling Mycallable for each one, I want 
    // to do it in batches of 10***

    Iterable<Customer> customerIterable=repo.findAll();
    List<Customer> customers=new ArrayList<Customer>();
    customerIterable.forEach(customers::add);


    for(Customer c:customers) {
        MyCallable myCallable= new MyCallable(restTemplate, c);
        Future<String> future= executor.submit(myCallable);
        myFutureList.add(future);
    }

    for(Future<String> fut:myFutureList) {
        fut.get();
    }
    executor.shutdown();

    long timeElapsed= (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000)-startTime;

    System.out.println("->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Time Elapsed In Multi Threaded Post Call<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<-"+timeElapsed);
    return "Success";

}
```

My Callable:

```
@Scope("prototype")
@Component
public class MyCallable implements Callable<String>{

  private RestTemplate restTemplate;
  private Customer c;

  public MyCallable(RestTemplate rt, Customer cust) {
        this.restTemplate = rt;
        this.c = cust;
    }

@Override
public String call() throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Customer no"+ c.getId() +"On thread Number"+Thread.currentThread().getId());
    restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:3000/save", c, String.class);
    return "Done";

}

}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: If you are "using JPA" then please post some actual JPA API code, like where you are doing a query

Comment: No Billy I am using spring-data-jpa. I have updated the question. If you have any solution, please help

Answer (score 1):

[Spring Data JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) offers [`Page`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html) and [`Slice`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Slice.html) to handle this case (see [`PagingAndSortingRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html) and [`Pageable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html))

```
public interface PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> 
  extends CrudRepository<T, ID> {

  Iterable<T> findAll(Sort sort);

  Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

You can create Pageable request as:

```
Pageable firstPageWithTwoElements = PageRequest.of(0, 2);
```

and pass it to your custom repository (which should extend [`PagingAndSortingRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html)):

```
Page<T> pageResult = customRepository.findAll(firstPageWithTwoElements);
```

Comment: For fetching 50 records I have to make a request like PageRequest.of(0,50). Then for another 50 records, I have to increase the page number to 1 like, PageRequest.of(1,50) right? That means to get all the records from the db I have to loop increasing the page number in each iteration? Correct me if I am wrong please.

Comment: You can call getTotalPages() on the Page class (which does a count query) to know how many pages are there and implement your logic based on that. If you don't care about the number of pages, you can work with Slice and call hasNext() before fetching the next Slice. Just read the API in the provided links or look for more detailed examples for PageRequest, Page and Slice.